# List names of directors

Tags: sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT director.lastname, director.firstname
FROM director LEFT JOIN movdir ON director.dirnum = movdir.dirnum
```

This is what I have right now, but I have to look at a `movdir` table and see if `dirnum(director number)` only shows up once. If it does, I have to go to the `director` table and see what their name is by looking at `dirnum` and see whose name is attached to that number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `GROUP BY` with `HAVING`-clause:

```
SELECT director.lastname, director.firstname
FROM director 
INNER JOIN movdir ON director.dirnum = movdir.dirnum
GROUP BY director.lastname, director.firstname
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: List the movies which have more than one director.  Include the year the movie was released and the movie title. Sort the output by title in alphabetical order. 

SELECT director.lastname, director.firstname
FROM director INNER JOIN movdir ON director.dirnum = movdir.dirnum
GROUP BY director.lastname, director.firstname
HAVING (((Count(*))>1));

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from DBA_DIRECTORIES
```

It will list directory name and path.